# Sending Google Doc email template as html format on Email

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail

I've google docs template with logo and some images plus some text instructions, and I want to send it over email exactly how it appear in Google Docs, I know how to send plain text from google docs but can't figure out how to send templates with images.

Here is the code I am using currently :-

```
      var body = doc.getBody().getText();
      var message = body;
      var subject = "subject line";
      MailApp.sendEmail (user.primaryEmail, subject, message)
```

Updated script as suggested by Tanaike :-

```
function getDocAsHtml(docId){ 
var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument()
var url = "https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/documents/export/Export?exportFormat=html&id=" + doc.getId();
var html = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, { headers: { authorization: "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() } }).getContentText();
var body = doc.getBody().getText();
var message = body;
var subject = "subject line";
MailApp.sendEmail('abc@xyz.com', subject, message, { htmlBody: html });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to send an email as the HTML body of the Google Document.

In this case, how about the following modification? From your showing script, I suppose that `doc` is the object of Document.

#### Modified script:

```js
var url = "https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/documents/export/Export?exportFormat=html&id=" + doc.getId();
var html = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, { headers: { authorization: "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() } }).getContentText();
var body = doc.getBody().getText();
var message = body;
var subject = "subject line";
MailApp.sendEmail(user.primaryEmail, subject, message, { htmlBody: html });
// DriveApp.getFiles(); // This is used for automatically detecting the scope of Drive API.
```

- When this script is run, the Google Document of `doc` is sent as the HTML body.

#### Note:

- In this case, the mail client cannot show the HTML body, the text body of `message` is shown.

#### References:

- [fetch(url, params)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl,-params)
- [sendEmail(recipient, subject, body, options)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendemailrecipient,-subject,-body,-options)

Comment: Thanks for response, but when I tried I got this error `Exception: Request failed for https://docs.google.com returned code 401`

Comment: ＠ankit_dot　Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. About `but when I tried I got this error Exception: Request failed for https://docs.google.com returned code 401`, unfortunately, when I tested my proposed script. No error occurs. I think that in this case, it is required to know your detail situation. So, can you provide your whole script for correctly replicating your current issue?

Comment: Please check, updated the full script

Comment: @ankit_dot Thank you for replying. When I saw your showing script, I understood your current issue. From your current script and your current issue of status code 401, it seems that you are not correctly using my proposed script. In my proposed script, I put a comment line of `// DriveApp.getFiles(); // This is used for automatically detecting the scope of Drive API.`. But your script doesn't include it. Please add this comment line. By this, the required scope is included.

Comment: Cool, thanks. It Worked. Sorry I thought it's just a comment :P

Comment: @ankit_dot Thank you for replying. It's no problem. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245440/discussion-between-ankit-dot-and-tanaike).