I converted a Google Doc to HTML to preserve formatting as an email body, but the email body loses that formatting from one day to the next
Yesterday with some help from other answers on this forum, I was able to use the below function to convert a Google Doc to HTML and use it as the body of an email to preserve most of the formatting from the Google Doc. The image below with blue and red text is the test email that I was successfully generating with the function.
However, today I added Utilities sleep() and saveAndClose commands to other functions in the script, but for some reason, this caused the formatting to be lost in the HTML email. The 2nd colorless image below is the email that's being generated now even after removing the few lines of code added earlier today. I gained the bullet points from the Google Doc, which is nice, but the spacing is off, and I've lost all font formatting.


Here is the function I've been using to convert the Google Doc body to HTML and use it as the body of an email that is then sent:
function sendEmail() {
  var contactEmail = 'MY_EMAIL'
  var emailSubject = 'test test'
  var doc = DocumentApp.openById('DOC_ID');
  var url = "https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/documents/export/Export?         exportFormat=html&id=" + doc.getId();
  var html = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, { headers: { authorization: "Bearer " +   ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() } }).getContentText();
  var body = doc.getBody().getText();
  var message = body;

  MailApp.sendEmail(contactEmail, emailSubject, message, { htmlBody: html });
  // DriveApp.getFiles(); // This is used for automatically detecting the scope of Drive API.
    }

And here is the link to the Google Doc template used as the email body.

Why are you using the message and the htmlBody at the same time? The body.getText() just returns a string. Use one or the other.

@Cooper I did it that way because this is what Tanaike had suggested in response to another question linked below. It worked fine for me yesterday. I've also tried the code below without any change.
MailApp.sendEmail(contactEmail, emailSubject, '', { htmlBody: html });

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72554738/sending-google-doc-email-template-as-html-format-on-email

Oh I didn't know that if it could not use the html it would use the message. So there must be something wrong with your fetch or the recipient won't accept html

The code is sending plain text content and HTML content. You should ensure that the email client is appropriately set always to display HTML content from email messages having HTML content.
